# URL Redirection not working after rewriting

Tags: .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I have written the URL Rewriting code in .htaccess file. I want to redirect from /CodecanyonSocial/settings.php to /CodecanyonSocial/index.php?a=profile&u=username
So I have done the code for rewriting. but it is not working. Here CodecanyonSocial is base(main) folder(site is in CodecanyonSocial folder).

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^CodecanyonSocial/index.php?a=profile&u=([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ CodecanyonSocial/settings.php [QSA,L]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: What is the URL you want to be in your browser?

Comment: You want to redirect from `/CodecanyonSocial/settings.php` to `/CodecanyonSocial/index.php?a=profile&u=username`. Where does `username` gets its value in this redirection?

Comment: It is in localhost and folder is CodecanyonSocial

Comment: @user3131633: You still didn't answer my question

Comment: from session variable

Comment: http://localhost:88/CodecanyonSocial/index.php?a=profile&u=username :I want this URL

Comment: You cannot read parameters from session in .htaccess

Comment: Then what should be the URL CodecanyonSocial/settings.php instead of this.

Comment: RewriteRule ^index.php?a=mentions/?$ /mentions.php? [QSA,L] is also not working.

Answer (score 0):

Just try this...

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /CodecanyonSocial/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^CodecanyonSocial/index.php?a=profile&u=([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ CodecanyonSocial/settings.php [QSA,L]

</IfModule>
```